# Using useTransform of framer-motion to clip-path

Tags: next.js, framer-motion

I tried to animate the `clip-path` using useTransform of framer-motion, but the value of useTransform it's like not compatible to `style: clipPath`

Here's my code:

[image: Full Code]

When animating the `x` and `y` of `translate` using `useTransform` it's okay, but in `clip-path` it's the value of `useTransform` is not compatible

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useTransform` returns a [motion value](https://www.framer.com/motion/motionvalue/), which is why you are seeing `[object Object]` when putting them in the string template. Framer Motion has a solution to adding a motion value to string templates called [`useMotionTemplate`](https://www.framer.com/motion/use-motion-template/). Here is how you would use it in your code:

```
const clipPath1 = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 1], [8, 0]);
const clipPath2 = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 1], [92, 100]);

const clipPath = useMotionTemplate`polygon(${clipPath1}% 0px, ${clipPath2}% 0px, ${clipPath2}% 100%, ${clipPath1}% 100%)`;

...

<motion.div
  style={{ clipPath }}
  ...
>
  ...
</motion.div>
```

Here is a [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/use-motion-template-framer-motion?file=app%2Fpage.tsx).

Comment: this is the exactly what I want, thank you so much :)